# Exclude some fields of REST Data with Panache

Tags: rest, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Just having a look at REST Data with Panache wondering if it is possible to exclude some entity fields from beeing exposed by the rest resource, as we need the generated REST resources only for read access pattern.

However, in the docs https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-data-panache I did not find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is using Jackson for JSON, so `@JsonIgnore` should work for you.

`@JSonIgnore` can be used at the field level, or you can add it on the Getter or Setter if you want only specific parts to be ignored.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_item")
public class OrderItem extends PanacheEntityBase {

  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @Column(name = "id", length = 36, nullable = false)
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String id;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Order.class)
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
  private Order orderId;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Item.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
  private Item itemId;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "quantity", nullable = false)
  private Integer quantity;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "price_total", nullable = false)
  private Double priceTotal;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Column(name = "note", columnDefinition = "text")
  private String note;

}
```

Or you can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at the top level of the class:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "creator", "created" }, allowSetters = false, allowGetters = true)
public class UpdateUserDeviceTokenRequest extends PanacheEntity {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    public String userDeviceToken;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "creatorUser", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    public AppUser creator;
    @Column(insertable = true, updatable = false)
    public LocalDateTime created;

    public UpdateUserDeviceTokenRequest() {
    }

    @PrePersist
    void onCreate() {
        this.created = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public UpdateUserDeviceTokenRequest(@NotNull @NotEmpty @NotBlank String userDeviceToken) {
        super();
        this.userDeviceToken = userDeviceToken;
    }

}
```

Please see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10339 for possible issue that might arise

Comment: OK that's a way to get it working. I was hoping that there is a way to define it in the rest Interfaces because IMO the entities should not have information about their rest representation. I would rather create separate classes and map the values to them tbh